# How can I draw line intersecting the arc perpendicularly(Core Graphics)?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want to draw a line on the circle(intercepting the arc of the circle) perpendicularly like in the picture.

I am using this code to draw circle

```
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2)

let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: Conversion.degreesToRadians(value: CGFloat(0)), endAngle: Conversion.degreesToRadians(value: CGFloat(360)), clockwise: true)
path.lineWidth = 2
path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.square
UIColor.white.setStroke()
path.stroke()
```

[image]

Comment: Is the question how to do CoreGraphics? (Usually you wouldn't even use CoreGraphics, but instead `stroke` a `UIBezierPath` or add a `CAShapeLayer`.) Or is the question the math behind how how to figure the starting and ending point of those line segments? Do you know how to draw the circle, itself? As it is, this question feels too broad.

Comment: Put your code to draw circle and also from where to put lines

Comment: how to figure the starting and ending point of those line segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is that a circle has a certain radius about a center `CGPoint`. To figure out a point on the circle, you can calculate the x and y coordinates like so:

```
func point(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
    let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

where the angle is measured in radians, starting at 3 o'clock and going clockwise.

So those perpendicular intersecting strokes are merely line segments between two `CGPoint` at a given angle, where the "radius" used for the start of the line segment might be, for example, something just less than the radius of the circle. For the ending point of the line, use the same angle, but then use a radius value just greater than the radius of the circle.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Love ur answer